# Store for loop results as a variable in bash

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop

I have a loop similar to the following:

```
for time in ${seconds_list}; do
    echo "scale=2; (${cur_time}-${time})/3600" | bc
done
```

Of course, I could "echo" the results to a file and be done with it, but I think a more elegant approach would be to store all the for-loop results in one variable, that I could use at a later time.
The variable containing all results would have to look something like this:

```
var='30.25
16.15
64.40
29.80'
```

Is there an easy way in which I can achieve this?

Comment: What are you *doing* with this data? It sounds like you're trying to help us implement your solution rather than solve your underlying problem. That makes this an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Sure, you can do this the way you're suggesting. Or other ways. But the best choice depends on details that are not ([yet](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36223802/edit)) in your question.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's really easy, you can just redirect the output of the whole loop to a variable (if you want to use just one variable as stated):

```
VARIABLE=$(for time in ...; do ...; done)
```

your example:

```
var=$(for time in ${seconds_list}; do
          echo "scale=2; (${cur_time}-${time})/3600" | bc
      done)
```

Just enclosing your code into $().

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe I did not think of that!

Comment: Spent forever looking for an answer like this. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Better to use a BASH array to store your results:

```
results=()

for time in ${seconds_list}; do
    results+=($(bc -l <<< "scale=2; ($cur_time-$time)/3600"))
done

# print the results:

printf "%s\n" "${results[@]}"
```

Comment: I prefer this version because, on another scenario, maybe you have stuff inside the loop you don't want to record in your variable. I like that this is inside and records that, specifically. Thanks!